# Techniques for probing circuits that would normaly be covered by a heatsink

Tags: measurement, heatsink, prototyping

I have a circuit board I have to probe and measure to first debug and then later on verify performance. The circuit board contains a power amplifier that requires a heatsink in order to keep the temperature in check. This heatsink is incorporated in the shield of this power amplifier. However, I now need to probe around this system (checking bias currents and voltages, etc.). For obvious reasons this is not possible when the shield is fitted.

On larger packages I would get small stick-on heatsinks on the package to keep them cool while measuring. In this case I am dealing with a 4x4 mm QFN, and I cannot find any heatsinks quite that small. When measuring other parts of the circuit I can just put a bigger heatsink on, but the smallest heatsink I have is 6x6 mm, and that already covers a lot of bias resistors around the package.

What are good techniques to cool this component? Right now I am thinking of just sticking down copper blocks that I saw to size, but I wonder if there are more elegant tricks to this.

Ofcourse, I could try connecting tiny wires to the points I want to measure and then install the heatsink, but I would prefer a solution that does not require me to dissasemble, solder on a wire, and reassemble every time I want to measure something.

Comment: Perhaps this application note can be of help: "AND8432 Thermal Considerations for a 4x4 mm QFN"

Comment: That application note (at least if it is the one I came across when Googleing) refers to PCB techniques to use the PCB as heatsink. In this case we are also useing an external heatsink to cool the system further.

Comment: What is the thermal resistance of the chip without the heatsink and what is the thermal resistance of the heatsink?

Comment: *"I would prefer a solution that does not require me to dissasemble, solder on a wire, and reassemble every time I want to measure something."* That's what test points are for. You should have thought about this when you were laying out the PCB. Live and learn!

Comment: @DaveTweed yes and no. These are bias pins to a RF amplifier and I don't want lines going out to testpoints acting like antennas.

Comment: Maybe you should have mentioned that in your question. You didn't seem to mind adding discrete wires to make your measurements. But in that case, you add the necessary filtering (chokes and decoupling capacitors) to the test points. Or even just a tiny zero-ohm resistor that you depopulate once your measurements are finished. Since this is a first prototype, you can afford to use board space that you otherwise can eliminate in the respin once you've got the electrical design optimized.